# How to add events to a user who has successfully logged in using google to my MERN Stack application?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api, passport.js, google-oauth

I've been having a lot of trouble adding events to a user's google calendar after they have completed signing into to my application using Google.
There are no "errors" as such, just that all the events that get added are only visible in the account that I registered with for the Google Developer Console. (I must be doing something stupid, but I really am new to do this and have no clue what's wrong).

I used passport.js for the OAuth process. The idea is, whenever someone hits the /calendarcreate route
it generates this event and adds it to their calendar.

Can anyone help me with adding events to the logged in user's calendar, and not the developer's calendar?

This is the code that I've written for it.

```
const passport = require("passport");
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {OAuth2} = google.auth;
const keys = require("../config/keys");
module.exports = app => {
  app.get(
    "/auth/google",
    passport.authenticate("google", {
      scope: ["profile", "email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"]
    })
  );
  app.get(
    "/auth/google/redirect",
    passport.authenticate("google"),
    (req, res) => {
      res.redirect("http://localhost:5000/dashboard");
    }

  );



app.get("/api/current_user", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.user);
    res.send(req.user);
  });



app.get("/api/logout", (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/");
  });
app.get("/calendarcreate",(req,res)=>{
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
  "GOOGLE CLIENT ID FROM DEV CONSOLE",
  "GOOGLE CLIENT SECRET","localhost:5000/dashboard"
 );
      oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        refresh_token : 
            "REFRESH_TOKEN", 
        access_token :
          "ACCESS TOKEN"
    })


    var event = {
      'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
      'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
      'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
      'start': {
        'dateTime': '2020-04-22T09:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata',
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': '2020-04-22T17:00:00-07:00',
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Kolkata',
      },
      'reminders': {
        'useDefault': false,
        'overrides': [
          {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
          {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
        ],
      },
    };



var calendar = google.calendar({version : 'v3', auth: oauth2Client});
  calendar.events.insert({
    auth : oauth2Client,
    calendarId: 'primary',
    resource: event,
    visibility : "public"
  }, function(err, event) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('There was an error contacting the Calendar service: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Event created: %s', event.data.htmlLink);
  });
  })
};
```

Comment: Do you assign scopes  when authorizing? If so, please provide your full code for better understanding.

Comment: Hey, @ziganotschka I updated it with all the code on the file. Yes, the scopes were assigned. Just not able to understand why it's adding the event to my developer email ID that i registered with on the Dev Console, instead of the logged in user's account's calendar.

Comment: And where do you get the tokens from?

Comment: @ziganotschka from the OAuth playground in google developers for the calendar API

Comment: @ziganotschka Okay, i think i'm beginning to understand why it's adding only to my developer account's calendar - because the tokens were generated for that account only?

How can i go about generating a refresh and access token for a user that logs into my application with google?

Comment: But those are your token, not the user's ones ! For Web Apps, the token should be retrieved as specified under [Retrieve access token](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#retrieve-access-token).

Comment: Also, you need to generate an authentication URL.

Answer (score 0):

- Create you oauth2Client as following

```
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
  YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET,
  YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
);
```

- You do not need `setCredentials` for your case
- Instead, define calendar service as
  `var calendar = google.calendar({version : 'v3', auth: oauth2Client});` with `oauth2Client` as defined above
- Then use `calendar.events.insert({...` without specifying `auth` a second time
- Find more information for creating a Google APIs Node.js Client [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client).

Comment: I tried this without set credentials, and it said Calendar Service Error : No access token, refresh token or API key is set

Comment: Try to include `auth: oauth2Client` within the `calendar.events.insert` request, but without   `setCredentials`.